# Capturing Key Presses on Blackberry Keypad

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to capture a key press on the return key.  How do I set up event listener for the enter key.  So far I can't find anything in the Blackberry docs about onKeyListener or anything like it.

All I want is to process 2 EditFields once the enter key is pressed.

Thanks,
MD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a [KeyListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/KeyListener.html) plus the [KeyPad](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Keypad.html) class to compare the key pressed with the keypad.